# What are the parameters in arow function in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

please help the newbie figure it out.

There is such a code:

```
    function makeDouble (x) {
      return x * 2; 
   }
    var doMath = (x, func) => func(x + 5);

   var num = 5;
```

The task is:

*Using only makeDouble, doMath, and num, make the value of num equal to 20.

num = _____________________________________________________*

I can’t understand why there are two parameters in the parameters of an arrow function, but in the body of this function itself there is only one parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer to the problem is `num=doMath(num, makeDouble)` and doMath accept 2 params, one value and one function, then call the function with 5 being added to the value passed. You may get a detailed answer by someone. I can't do that now because I'm on my mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You can translate the arrow function as:

```
function doMath(x, func) { return func(x+5); }
```

So you pass a value (x) and a function (func) to the doMath function. func can be any function, for example makeDouble... You can call it like:

```
doMath(1, makeDouble)
```

And the result will be (1+5)*2 = 12.

I think you can figure out the rest based on this.

Comment: To expand conceptually, this concept is known as a [callback](https://javascript.info/callbacks). 

Essentially, the doMath function is accepting another function as an argument so that doMath can call the `func` argument within it's scope.

Answer (score 1):

Both parameters in `doMath()` are being used. The first is argument `x` will be applied as an argument in the function call of the second argument `func` and the value returned from that function call will be returned by `doMath()` itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is
`num = doMath(num, makeDouble)`

There are also 2 parameters in the body of the function.
Let's look a little bit closer
`func(x+5)`

func is a second parameter of the function and x that we pass to it is a first parameter

Answer (score 1):

Here, `func` is a callback function. In javascript, you can pass a `function` as a parameter just like you pass any other variable, for e.g, an integer, object or an array. So here in `doMatch` you're passing a number and a callback function. When `doMatch` executes, it calls `func` with the parameter `10` (5+5). `Func`, now, will be executed and will return `2*10` (20)

```js
  function makeDouble (x) {
      return x * 2; 
   }
    var doMath = (x, func) => func(x + 5);

   var num = 5;

console.log(doMath(num, makeDouble))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeDouble (x) {
  return x * 2; 
}
const doMath = (x, func) => func(x + 5);

const num = 5;

let result = doMath(num, makeDouble); 

console.log(result);// 20
```

`doMath(x, func)` is an arrow function which takes two parameters. The first para meters is your numeric value, and the second is a function which in this case is `makeDouble(x)`. Inside the arrow function, the `makeDouble(x)` function is called with the numeric parameter + 5 like `makeDouble( num + 5)`. In this case, num is added five inside the constructor, so this time makeDouble returns the product of 10 * 2. Also, I would suggest to revise the use of var. Currently the use of let and const is preferred over var.

Arrow functions can take other functions as parameters, which is great to work with recursion and functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

Thank very much you all!

My problem was that I did not notice that the makeDouble() function in the parameters of the arrow function did not return the value, but the content of the function itself. And then in the body of the arrow function, it can be to call the makeDouble() function as a parameter.